# Change element style on a image inside a iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to change the element-style of the img inside the iframe using jquery. The iframe epubjs-iframe change the id on every page load. What I want is to change the style = `heigh="98%"` to `max-height:467` and `width:auto` on every page load.

[Html-code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3swV.png)

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: I am using epubjs from futurepress. And when I load the cover page the cover image splits up and isnt responsive. So by using inspect element in chrome I change the values <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/152c9309-f019-473e-b88c-3d5deef4b45a" style="height:98%;" alt="Image">  to max-height: 467 and width:auto. Since I cant reach the iframe from my internal css I was wondering if its possible to use jquery on every load and change the element.style to the values which works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IF the `src` of your iframe is pointing to SAME domain.

Eg.

```
var iframe = $("#iframe"); // Selector to get the iframe
$("#elemInIframe", iframe.contents()).css("color", "blue"); //Or whatever method you want
```

And Of course, if the `src` of iframe is in different domain, due to security reasons, You will not be able to access the contents in javascript. Sorry about the same!!

Answer (score 0):

Not know if it is the case here, but when working with iframes You may need to overcome Same Origin Policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

You can use PostMessage for cross-frame communication. To do so:

- You need to be in control of the code both host page and embedded one
- Or use the PostMessage API provided by page You want to embed

More about PostMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage